# Limit of $\{i^n\},\{z_0^n\}$ for $\left|z_0\right|<1,\{\frac{\cos n+i\sin n}{n}\},\{\frac{n!i^{n}}{n^{n}}\},\{n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^{n}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Which one of the following sequences is convergent?

- $\{i^n\}$
- $\{z_0^n\}$ for $\left|z_0\right|<1$
- $\{\frac{\cos n+i\sin n}{n}\}$
- $\{\frac{n!i^{n}}{n^{n}}\}$
- $\{n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^{n}\}$

---

The first sequence is not convergent since for $n=4k,4k+2$ for some positive integer $k$ we have that :
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}i^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}i^{4k}=1$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}i^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}i^{4k+2}=-1$$

---

For the second one the limit is $0$ since $\left|z_{n}^{n}-0\right|=\left|z_{0}\right|^{n}$, So if $N=\lceil \log_{ \left|z_{0}\right|}\epsilon\rceil +1$ then for every positive $\epsilon$ and for every $n$ positive integer if $n \ge \lceil \log_{ \left|z_{0}\right|}\epsilon\rceil +1$ it follows that  $n > \lceil \log_{ \left|z_{0}\right|}\epsilon\rceil
\ge \log_{ \left|z_{0}\right|}\epsilon$ which implies $$\left|z_{0}^{n}-0\right|=\left|z_{0}\right|^{n}<\epsilon$$

---

For the third one let $N=\lceil 2/\epsilon\rceil +1$ then for every positive $\epsilon$ and for every $n$ positive integer if $n \ge \lceil 2/\epsilon\rceil +1$ it follows that $n > \lceil 2/\epsilon\rceil
\ge 2/\epsilon$ which implies $$\left|\frac{\cos n+i\sin n}{n}-0\right|\le\frac{\left|\cos n\right|+\left|i\right|\left|\sin n\right|}{n}$$$$=\frac{\left|\cos n\right|+\left|\sin n\right|}{n}\le\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon$$

---

For the fourth one $N=\lceil \log_{ 2}1/\epsilon^2\rceil +1$ then for every positive $\epsilon$ and for every $n$ positive integer if $n \ge \lceil \log_{ 2}1/\epsilon^2\rceil +1$ it follows that  $n > \lceil \log_{ 2}1/\epsilon^2\rceil 
\ge \log_{ 2}1/\epsilon^2$ which implies $$\epsilon>\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\ge\frac{n!}{n^{n}}=\left|\frac{n!}{n^{n}}i^{n}-0\right|$$

---

About the last one, I don't know if the sequence if convergent or not. I want to know whether my answers are correct or not, so if you have an alternative answer first check mine and approve/disapprove the validity and then provide yours.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. For the last one note that $|n(\frac {1+i} 2)^{n}|=n2^{-n/2} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. You can check that $n2 ^{-n/2} \leq 2^{-n/4}$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Also, $2^{-n/4} <\epsilon$ if $n >4\log_2(\frac 1 {\epsilon})$.

[ $2^{n/4}>(1+0.1)^{n}$. You can now use Binomal expansion up to  the third term to show that $2^{n/4}>n$ for $n$ sufficiently large].

Answer (score 0):

(i), (ii) are ok to me.

For (iii), you can remark that $\cos n + i\sin n=e^{in}$, so that
$$\left|\frac{\cos n + i\sin n}{n}\right|= \left|\frac{e^{in}}{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}$$ (but what you did is ok)

For (iv), in $|\cdot|$, $i^n$ doesn't matter, so you can compare $n!$ and $n^n$ by developping these two expressions and compare term to term (but again what you did is ok)

For (v), you can write $\frac{1+i}{2}$ in the trigonometric way.